# check if caret exist or is visible in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#clickme').on('click',function(){
     console.log("caret exists"); // or
     console.log("caret doesn't exist");
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  border : 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" contenteditable = "true"></div><br>
<button id='clickme'>Click</button>
```

In the above code, on button click how to find out if caret exist in contenteditable div or not.

Comment: If you're clicking on the button then the button will have focus so the caret will never be in the contenteditable element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are right, now the question makes no sense